# OpenGL Collisions between 2 spheres sometimes not detected

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

For this project i use OpenGl.

I'm trying to detect the collision between two spheres, I think it's pretty simple.
It works but sometimes (very often actually...) the collision between these two spheres is not detected, and I really don't know why...
I tried to change the algorithm of detection and it allways ends by a non detection sometimes...

```
void MyGlWindow::checkMoverIsHit()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_container->m_movers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (m_container->m_ball != m_container->m_movers[i]) {
            float size = m_container->m_ball->m_size + m_container->m_movers[i]->m_size;
            if (size >= (m_container->m_ball->m_position - m_container->m_movers[i]->m_position).magnitude())
            {
                score += 10;
                m_container->m_movers.erase(std::remove(m_container->m_movers.begin(), m_container->m_movers.end(), m_container->m_movers[i]), m_container->m_movers.end());
                for (size_t i = 0; i < (score / 10) + 1; i++)
                    createMover();
                reload();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call this function in my update function

```
void MyGlWindow::update()
{
    TimingData::get().update();

    if (!run) return;

    float lastFrameDuration = (float)TimingData::get().lastFrameDuration;

    float duration = lastFrameDuration * 0.003;

    totalTimePrecise += lastFrameDuration;
    totalTimeSec = totalTimePrecise / 1000;

    if (totalTimeSec > 60) {
        writeBestScoreInFile();
        restart();
    }

    if (totalTimeSec == 40)
        windBlowing = true;

    if (duration <= 0.0f) return;

    m_container->update(duration);

    if (windBlowing == true)
        m_container->windBlow();

    checkBallDetachFromAnchor();
    
    checkMoverIsHit(); // !!! ITS CALLED HERE !!!

    m_world->runPhysics(duration);
}
```

- m_container is my container of movers: it contains basically all the "movers" of my scene.
- m_container->m_ball is a pointer of one of these movers. It's the ball I launched to "shoot" the other movers.
- After I think everything is pretty clear, ask me if something is not.

Hope someone can help me... I've done everything in my project it's the only thing bugging !

Here is a GIF, the first ball worked, the second didn't:
[image: Example of collision detection bug between two spheres]

Comment: I noticed that (1) collision detection has nothing to do with OpenGL and (2) your second red ball went *over* the blue ball and did not collide with it.

Comment: From what I see, both collisions have been detected (the second ball reacted to the collision). The problem seems to be in how you show/update the score. What happens when you ```reload()``` ?

Comment: Hello Lucas, no the score is updating correctly. And the reload is just reloading the ball attached to the anchor. I finally find out what was the problem: I have just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to find out what was happening.

The problem is that my world is avoiding collisions. What I mean by that is: when two objects collide, they automatically bounce against each other.

This behaviour was the problem because the goal of my hunting ball is to collide against the other objects so.... randomly... it was not detecting some collisions, because it was boucing.

To fix it, I removed from my hunting ball the fact that it was iteracting with the other movers of the scene. So now it's only checking in my function `checkMoverIsHit();` if it's colliding with the other movers.

It now works perfectly.